# JENKINS running same job on multiple machines and same machine (based on executors)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

i'm new to jenkins and i'm trying to run a job which runs on mulitple machines.
this was achieved by **enabling this project is parameterized option** and selecting the suitable node and value. This will run the same job on multiple machines parallely but only 1 instane on each machine.

Now my question is i want the job to be run on all executors on all machines.
Let's say machine A has 4 executors and machine B has 2 executors
it should **run 6 times parallely** instead of 2.
Is there a way to achieve this in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can achieve this automatically - as I know, there are no plugins with such functionality.

Only way that I can propose you is to create additional job for triggering your job 6 times. However, you need to enable `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` option in your job. And then your job should execute 6 times in parallel (if not - try to use also [Heavy Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin) for specifying the total number of executors that the job should occupy).